# Circular linked list deletion at beginning

Tags: c, data-structures

My function is able to delete nodes at the front of the list if the list has more than one node.
If only one node remains in the list deletion does not take place..

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

//Circular linked list node structure
typedef struct circularLinkedListNode{
    int data;
    struct circularLinkedListNode *next;
}circularLinkedListNode;

circularLinkedListNode *head = NULL;

//Traversal of circular linked list
void traversal()
{
    circularLinkedListNode *current = head;

    if(current == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nThe list is empty!!");
    }
    else
    {
        do {
            printf("%d--", current->data);
            current = current->next;
        } while (current != head);
    }
}

//Insertion at the beginning of the list
void insertAtBeginning(int data)
{
    circularLinkedListNode *newNode = (circularLinkedListNode *)malloc(sizeof(circularLinkedListNode));

    //Create a new node and point it to itself
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = newNode;

    if(head == NULL)
    {
        head = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        circularLinkedListNode *current = head;
        while (current->next != head) {
            current = current->next;
        }
        current->next = newNode;
        newNode->next = head;
        head = newNode;
    }
}

//Insertion at the end of the list
void insertAtEnd(int data)
{
    circularLinkedListNode *newNode = (circularLinkedListNode *)malloc(sizeof(circularLinkedListNode));
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = newNode;

    if(head == NULL)
    {
        head = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        circularLinkedListNode *current = head;
        while(current->next != head)
        {
            current = current->next;
        }
        newNode->next = head;
        current->next = newNode;
    }
}
```

MAIN PROBLEM IS ON THIS FUNCTION:::::

```
//Deletion of node at the beginning
void deleteATBeginning()
{
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nEmpty list!!");
    }
    else
    {
        circularLinkedListNode *nodeToDelete = head;
        circularLinkedListNode *current = head;
        while(current->next != head)
        {
            current = current->next;
        }
        current->next = head->next;
        head = head->next;
        free(nodeToDelete);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int data, choice;

    while (1)
    {
        printf("\n***CIRCULAR LINKED LIST***\n1.Traversal\n2.Insertion at the beginning\n3.Insertion at the end\n4.Deletion of front node\n5.Deletion of end node\n6.Exit\nEnter your choice: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        switch (choice)
        {
            case 1:
                traversal();
                break;

            case 2:
                printf("Enter the data: ");
                scanf("%d", &data);
                insertAtBeginning(data);
                break;

            case 3:
                printf("Enter the data: ");
                scanf("%d", &data);
                insertAtEnd(data);
                break;

            case 4:
                deleteATBeginning();
                break;

            case 6:
                return 0;
                break;

            default:
                printf("Wrong choice!! Please try again...");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it a true circular list even with one node, I.e. does the node point to itself when a single element is all that is left ? If not, it should, as that is important. Just making sure.

Comment: yes even with single node in the list, the node points to itself..

Comment: Ok, last question, is this list doubly-linked, or just singly? I don't see a `prev` pointer, being the only reason I ask. That would explain why you're enumerating to the end of the list, something you wouldn't have to do with a double-link implementation.

Comment: It is singly linked list

Comment: typedef struct circularLinkedListNode{
    int data;
    struct circularLinkedListNode *next;
}circularLinkedListNode;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks a bit convoluted, but it should work. I think when you say "the list deletion does not take place" you're not looking for it happening correctly.

You are looking for head to become `null` to confirm that the deletion took place:

```
if(head == NULL)
{
    printf("\nEmpty list!!");
```

but you never account for the special case of a deletion of the only node in the list, thus head will never become `null` (that doesn't happen on its own).

This can be as simple as:

```
if(head->next == head) // if the head's next node is itself
{
    head->next = null;
    free(nodeToDelete);
    head = null;
} 
else
{
    while(current->next != head)
    {
        current = current->next;
    // ...rest of your code as is
```

Your code is currently `free`'ing the memory pointed to by `head` but it is not releasing (`null`'ing) the memory location, so your `head` pointer is still pointing to memory, but this memory no longer is owned by your program. This is a dangling pointer. You probably still see the node's contents as "valid" but that's only by chance as nothing else has come in and reassigned memory at this point.

Comment: +1 Just started typing up the failure to detect self-referencing head node (and tried to elude to said-same in comment). Thanks for saving me the keystrokes. nice answer.

Comment: Thanx man.... you solved my query... would ask the writer of the book to change his code to take this case into consideration :)

Comment: But if this wasn't a circular linked list.. would my code work correct??

Comment: @user2035503 - Linked lists (be they circular or not) have special cases, this is where there are no nodes or 1 node mostly. There always has to be special handling for these cases. As I said in the answer, your code technically already *worked*, but you left the pointer dangling, normally one would clean up pointers (set them to `null`) when they're not in use anymore. So short answer: no, as is, your code isn't completely correct regardless of the list type.